# Performance of State in a certain case is slower than I would expect. Why?

Tags: haskell

Consider the function `reverseAndMinimum` (slightly modified from [another answer nearby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49168835)):

```
import Control.Monad.State.Strict

reverseAndMinimum' :: Ord a => [a] -> State a [a] -> State a [a]
reverseAndMinimum' [ ] res = res
reverseAndMinimum' (x:xs) res = do
        smallestSoFar <- get
        when (x < smallestSoFar) (put x)
        reverseAndMinimum' xs ((x:) <$> res)

reverseAndMinimum :: Ord a => [a] -> ([a], a)
reverseAndMinimum [ ] = error "StateSort.reverseAndMinimum: This branch is unreachable."
reverseAndMinimum xs@(x:_) = runState (reverseAndMinimum' xs (return [ ])) x
```

It traverses the argument only once; however, it is about 30% slower than a naive function that does it two times:

```
reverseAndMinimum_naive :: Ord a => [a] -> ([a], a)
reverseAndMinimum_naive xs = (reverse xs, minimum xs)
```

It also consumes about 57% as much memory.

Here are the relevant extracts from a run with `+RTS -s`:

*`reverseAndMinimum`*

```
     176,672,280 bytes allocated in the heap
...

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.064s  (  0.063s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.311s  (  0.311s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.005s  (  0.005s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.379s  (  0.380s elapsed)

  %GC     time      82.0%  (82.0% elapsed)
```

*`reverseAndMinimum_naive`*

```
     112,058,976 bytes allocated in the heap
...

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.041s  (  0.040s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.245s  (  0.245s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.005s  (  0.005s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.291s  (  0.291s elapsed)

  %GC     time      84.2%  (84.3% elapsed)
```

What's happening, how can I diagnose, is it possible to improve?

**P.S.** A handy `main` for running tests:

```
main = do
    top <- (read :: String -> Int) . (!! 0) <$> getArgs
    val <- evaluate . force $ reverseAndMinimum (take top [top, top - 1.. 1 :: Int])
    print $ (\x -> (last . fst $ x, snd x)) $ val
```

Comment: Why is `reverseAndMinimum'` listed? Is it used at all? Also, what input did you use for the tests?

Comment: @MarkSeemann I lost an apostrophe. Will fix shortly. I used ascending and descending lists of length about 10^5.

Comment: How are you running it? Is it compiled with optimizations? (benchmarking with no optimizations is kind of meaningless since inlining is a big part of Haskell performance.) Are you using strict or lazy state? Strict gets much fewer allocations, though it's still slower than the naive version.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Yes, it is compiled with optimizations. I used lazy state; the strict takes exactly 2/3 as much space, which is great − but the processor cycles spent actually doing work appear the same.

Comment: I was confused because I didn't get measurements in the same order of magnitude (but the same relative ratio). I get the 300MB number with lists of length 10^(6). Also, `[1, 1..]` is a constant list.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Yes, it's constant, but I don't think it matters. I tried all kinds of lists. The proportion of values that are lower than the current minimum must be determining how often the state gets changed, but the impact of this seems to be minor: ascending and descending lists give very similar performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**: *this refers to a previous version of the question where `reverseAndMinimum :: Ord a => [a] -> State a ([a] -> [a])`.*

In the naive version, `reverse` is efficient because it can build up the reversed list directly while traversing the list, and `minimum` is ignored because it's not needed.

The "one pass" `reverseAndMinimum` allocates a difference list, that must be applied to yield an actual list which is then traversed again to find its last element.

---

Replicating the accumulator technique used in `reverse`, the following code compiles to a tight loop to compute the reverse and minimum of a list in one pass.

```
import Control.Monad.State.Strict

reverseAndMinimum :: Ord a => [a] -> ([a], a)
reverseAndMinimum [ ] = error "Empty list!"
reverseAndMinimum (x:xs) = runState (reverseAndMinimum' xs [x]) x

reverseAndMinimum' :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> State a [a]
reverseAndMinimum' [ ] acc = return acc
reverseAndMinimum' (x:xs) acc = do
    smallestSoFar <- get
    when (x < smallestSoFar) (put $ x)
    reverseAndMinimum' xs (x : acc)
```

Comment: I went on and got rid of dlist, borrowing from [`Prelude.reverse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#reverse) instead. It still runs slower than the naive implementation by about a third. Even if I print the minimum. (I actually `evaluate . force` everything now.) Can you produce code that achieves speedup?

Comment: I updated the post with, hopefully, more precise measurements, and the new code. Kindly take a look.

Comment: You almost got it! The accumulator needed to just be a list. I updated my answer.

Comment: Oh! This is actually **faster** than the naive variant **by** almost **23% !**

Comment: BTW there is a library for single-pass folds: [foldl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl).